# Magento 2 : Remove product attribute programmatically when install extension

Tags: product-attribute, magento2.2

I want to remove product attribute when I install extension. I found some solution using controller remove product attribute.

But, I want to remove it when install extension.

In magento 1 it's work like :

```
$setup = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup','catalog_setup');
$setup->removeAttribute('catalog_product','my_attribute');
```

But, How to do in Magento 2.2.3?

Answer (score 4):

You can remove it by adding the following code to the `app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/Setup/InstallData.php` file of your module (make sure to change the `my_attribute` value).

```
<?php

namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(
          \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'my_attribute');
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove attribute using below setup script :

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Company\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(
          \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'my_attribute');
    }
}
```